# how to disable the windows auto resize gesture thing?

Tags: vb.net

I'm not sure what to call it. For example when you move a window to the edge of the screen, it offers to cover half the screen with it, stuff like that. How do i disable that kind of functionality for a particular form?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to disable this behavior for a particular form? Do you, perhaps, want to prevent form resizing in general? Do you want to enforce a minimum form size?

Comment: no, i want the form to stay within the bounds of a container in its owner form. These windows gestures don't make any sense since the form couldn't possibly take that kind of shape anyway due to the rules i've set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Windows forms.

To prevent the window from being resized or moved in ways that you don't want, I'd handle the [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window message. This message is sent before a window is moved or resized, and your application can prevent moves and resizes by manipulating the `flags` member of the [WINDOWPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

I'm not aware of an methods built-in to .NET that map to this message's functionality directly. You'll probably have to override the WndProc method of your form.

For an example in C, see [Use WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING to intercept window state changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/16/7123299.aspx).